# Is there a command shortcut to get to a dialog box?

Tags: stata

Stata has these dialog boxes to configure commands (e.g., "Summary statistics")
[image: Summary statistics]

Is there any way to jump directly to these boxes from the command prompt rather than from the cascading menus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Chapter 2, The Stata user interface, in the Getting Started with Stata PDF,

> You may know the name of a Stata command for which you want to see a dialog, but you might not remember how to navigate to that command in the menu system. Simply type `db commandname` to launch the dialog for commandname ...

For your example, type `db summarize`.